# Django Polymoprhic

Tags: python, django, django-polymorphic

I want to implement models using inheritance and I've found this package `django-polymorphic`. But I was reading about inheritance in django models and almost on every page I found they recommend using `abstract = True` in parent model. Which will duplicate fields for subclasses, resultsing in making queries faster.

I've done some testing and found out that this library doesn't use use abstract varaible:

```
class Parent(PolymorphicModel):
    parent_field = models.TextField()

class Child(Parent):
    child_field = models.TextField()

This results in:
```

Parent table:

```
| app_parent| CREATE TABLE `app_parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_field` longtext NOT NULL,
  `polymorphic_ctype_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_polymorphic_ctype_id_a7b8d4c7_fk_django_content_type_id` (`polymorphic_ctype_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `app_polymorphic_ctype_id_a7b8d4c7_fk_django_content_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`polymorphic_ctype_id`) REFERENCES `django_content_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Child table:

| app_child | CREATE TABLE `app_child` (
  `parent_ptr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child_field` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_ptr_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `no_parent_ptr_id_079ccc0e_fk_app_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_ptr_id`) REFERENCES `app_arent` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Should I use my own classes which uses abstract field or should i stick with this?

Comment: Why do you want to use django-polymorphic? What is your reason? I like this library, because it solves something for me. What should it solve for you?

Comment: I have lots of similar tables for which I'd like to use inheritance. I want my code to be simple. I don't want to go through 5 different tables and change fields that are exactly the same. However I don't want really slow sql queries, but seeing that this package doesn't use abstract field I dont know how will this impact my performance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a need to be able to query parent table?

```
Parent.objects.all()
```

If yes, then most probably you will need to use the multi-table inheritance with `abstract=False`.

Using model inheritance with `abstract=False` you get more complicated database schema, with more database relations. Creating a child instance will take 2 inserts instead of 1 (parent and child table). Querying child data will require table join. So this method certainly has got it's shortcomings. But when you want to query for common columns data, it's best supported way in django.

Django polymorphic builds on top of standard django model inheritance, by adding extra column `polymorphic_ctype` which allows to identify subclass having only a parent object.

There are various ways that you can use to achieve similar results using `abstract=True`. But often it results in more complicated querying code.

If using `abstract=True` bellow is 2 examples how you can query common-data of all childs.

- Chaining multiple queries

  ```
  def query_all_childs(**kwargs):
      return chain(
          Child1.objects.filter(**kwargs)
          Child2.objects.filter(**kwargs)
      )
  ```
- Using database views

  Manually create a database view that combines several tables (this could be done by attaching sql code to [post-migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal):

  ```
  create database view myapp_commonchild
  select 'child1' as type, a, b from child1
  union all
  select 'child2' as type, a, b from child2
  ```

  Create a concrete-parent model with `managed=False`. This flag tells django to ignore the table in database migrations (because we have manually created database view for that).

  ```
  class Parent(models.Model):
      a = CharField()
      b = CharField()

  class CommonChild(Parent):
      type = models.CharField()
      class Meta:
          managed = False

  class Child1(Parent):
      pass

  class Child2(Parent):
      pass
  ```

  Now you can query `CommonChild.objects.all()` and access common fields of child classes.

Speaking of performance, I don't know how big your tables are or how heavy reads/writes are, but most probably using `abstract=False` will not impact your performance in a noticeable way.